# How to fetch email id from field and send mail to that

Tags: php, html

I have an Email Id field in the below code, once the user enters Email and clicks on submit, I want to fetch that email from the field and send thank you message to the fetched email id using php
**Can Any one Help me out**

```
<div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>
    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span></div>
<button name="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: to fetch data from field, first of all you need `form` element in your code, then choose `POST` or `GET` type, to send data. After that, in your `.php` code with SUPERGLOBAL ARRAY `$POST` or `$GET` you can fetch email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sandeep, Please check below code.First Contact form render on the page after fill email form disappears & thank-you message render on the page.

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_POST['email']))  {

  $to = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = 'Email Subject';
  $message = 'Welcome Messege';
   //send email
  mail($to, $subject, $message);
   //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }
  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
 <div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>
    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: its working but, if i just put email id and send it,it is escaping other validation(i have few more form elements in the page) and sending a mail to email

Comment: @sandeep S K, You can validate few more fields of your page also before sending email. You can put client-side (java-script) validation on the form fields. Can you please accept my answer if it helps to you ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $to      = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<div class="fluid div_form"><label><b>Email Id *:</b></label>

    <input type="email" size="20px" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" value=" <?php echo $email; ?> "/>
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span>

</div>
<button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its working but, if i just put email id and send it,it is escaping other validation(i have few more form elements in the page) and sending a mail to emai

Comment: you should mention it in your question as well.. You can do as Weblineindia has suggested..